# Pourquoi « lambda » ?

Tags: étymologie, argot

*[Lambda](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lambda)* peut prendre le sens de « quelconque », « banal » ou « moyen ». Le *TLFi* nous dit que ça vient de l'argot des grandes écoles (j'imagine qu'il y a au moins une école où il vaut mieux ne pas dire « un élève X » pour « un élève quelconque »), et le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/lambda) ajoute

> se dit, par allusion à la place de cette lettre dans l'alphabet grec, d'une personne que rien ne distingue dans sa catégorie.

Bon, certes, mais sait-on pourquoi « lambda » ? Mu, nu et rhô sont également au milieu de l'alphabet grec.

Comment: À vrai dire, j'ai peu d'espoir pour cette question… j'ai peur que ce soit simplement un hasard, une expression qui un jour prend sans qu'on puisse expliquer pourquoi celle-là et pas une autre. Considérez-là donc comme une sorte de bouteille à la mer !

Comment: Un rapport avec le lambda-calcul? http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-calcul

Comment: Il paraît que [le roi Louis XIII utilisait parfois cette lettre comme monogramme, comme sur les bas reliefs de la Cour Carrée du Louvre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda#Utilisations). Amusant — j'imagine que le roi n'était pas vraiment un citoyen lamba.

Comment: @Nikko va voir [là-bas](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64468) si j'y suis :)

Comment: @Nikko, le λ-calcul est un poil plus ancien que ce que ngram nous indique pour [individu lambda](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=individu+lambda&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=7) et λ ne désigne pas une variable dans ce calcul là.

Comment: Un quelconque lien avec l'individu japonnais « 人 » ? (Je ne pense pas, mais sait-on jamais.)

Comment: Je penche très fortement pour le hasard. Sachant qu'aucune des alternatives ("mu", "nu", "rho"...) ne me paraît viable pour une telle expression: monosyllabiques et peu suffisamment reconnaissables (essayez de dire "un élève nu" à voix haute, et je pense que ça paraitra évident ;-)

Comment: Ils aimaient probablement les danses exotiques dans les grandes écoles. Le deuxième *a* s'est perdu en chemin...

Comment: @Dave, *l'élève nu* s'approche de *l'élève X* de la question :)

Comment: Et l'élève voisin, mû par le nu, dit : « Rhôôôô ! »

Comment: J'aime bien l'hypothèse de @Stéphane, en effet, 人 comme λ peuvent être vus comme une représentation schématique de l'être humain, un torse et deux jambes.

Comment: @phil et ma réponse va dans ce sens également.

Comment: [Un livre](http://books.google.fr/books?id=SqtYAAAAMAAJ) sur le sujet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Les expressions françaises décortiquées](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/un-quelque-chose-lambda.php) pointent quand même vers une particularité de *lambda* que n'ont pas *mu*, *nu* ou *rhô* : plusieurs syllabes.

> Or, par sa position dans le même alphabet, lambda est la lettre dont le nom n'est pas monosyllabique qui est placée la plus proche du milieu, donc à une position très moyenne, très quelconque, où elle ne peut pas briller, où elle est un peu noyée dans la masse, contrairement à l'alpha et à l'oméga, les première et dernière lettres.
>   Ce serait là l'explication de l'utilisation de cette lettre.

Ce qui, à tout prendre, ne nous avance guère plus. En quoi le fait d'avoir plusieurs syllabes est-il important ?

Comment: … et pourquoi X, tout aussi utilisé, qui ne se trouve pas au milieu du tout et ne fait qu'une syllabe ?

Comment: Je dirais que c'est une [autre question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) : pourquoi utilise-t-on _x_ (ou _y_) pour désigner une inconnue ?

Comment: @cadrian X n'a pas la connotation qu'a lambda. un individu X c'est juste un individu inconnu, un individu lambda c'est en général utilisé pour désigner un type plus ordinaire que les autres. (Sauf si c'est écrit « individu λ » dans un bouquin de math, et là c'est juste une inconnue).

Comment: et pourquoi pas omega?

Comment: @Nikko omega est aussi extrême qu'alpha. En simplifiant, alpha = très bon, début ; oméga = très mauvais, fin ; lambda = quelconque.

Comment: Ça aurait pu être delta, théta, entre autres...

Comment: Je pense que X vient de la signature des personnes qui ne savaient pas écrire. On leur demandait de signer d'une croix, ce qui rend le truc plutot anonyme, non ?

Answer (score 18):

Je n'ai pas réussi à remonter à l'origine de l'expression. mais elle semble bien être au départ de l'argot de l'[École polytechnique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_polytechnique_%28France%29). Elle était déjà employée par [la promotion 1938](http://www.lajauneetlarouge.com/articles/polytechnique--largot-de-lx-en-1938-jai-vu-le-gnass-dunablat-avec-un-chamo-cornecul-3695/largot-de-lx/2010-11-num-659.html). Elle a mis un certain temps à se répandre hors de ce petit milieu ; en 1955, dans son [*Essai sur la langue de la réclame contemporaine*](http://books.google.com/books?id=2H4tAAAAMAAJ&q=%22individu+lambda%22&dq=%22individu+lambda%22&hl=en&ei=VBhxTt-lJ-mj4gT868XECQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ), Marcel Galliot l'explique ainsi :

> assez timidement : *lambda*, dans un emploi venu de l'argot polytechnicien : les mathématiciens ayant coutume d'employer les premières lettres de l'alphabet pour désigner des quantités connues et de réserver les dernières pour les inconnues, les lettres du milieu, et notamment le λ, s'appliquent à des grandeurs quelconques. D'où l'expression : un individu *lambda* [...], désignant un individu quelconque, le premier venu. Nous avons entendu plusieurs fois cette expression depuis quelques années.

Pourquoi lambda plutôt qu'une de ses proches voisines ? Je pense que c'est parce que lambda est naturellement le début d'une série (`λ`, `μ`, `ν`, éventuellement `ξ`), la lettre `κ` étant souvent évitée à cause du risque de confusion avec le `k` ou `K` latin.

Pour aller un peu plus loin sur l'historique, avant les années 1980, la base documentaire de Google ne contient que de rares occurrences isolées ; ensuite elle semble entrer dans la langue courante (et ne pas mériter d'explication).

[individu lambda,citoyen lambda,lecteur lambda http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=individu%20lambda%2Ccitoyen%20lambda%2Clecteur%20lambda&corpus=7&smoothing=3&year_start=1900&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=individu+lambda%2Ccitoyen+lambda%2Clecteur+lambda&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)

Le [corpus de l'université de Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/ws_fra/) montre une utilisation biaisée vers des mots associés aux ordinateurs et à Internet, avec des voisins de gauche tels que *contributeur*, *utilisateur* ou *visiteur*. C'est en partie un artéfact du corpus (qui est composé environ pour moitié de pages web, dont notamment Wikipédia), mais le biais n'est pas particulièrement apparent pour *quelconque*.

Comment: La première occurrence remonte un peu avant la promotion 1938 : il est [mentionné dans _Le Nouvel Argot de l'X_ de 1936](http://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=nuoeAQAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=lambda) ; son auteur Roger Smet [étant semble-t-il de la promotion 1931](https://www.polytechnique.org/search?quick=roger+smet), le terme était vraisemblablement en usage vers 1932 (X1931 = à l'X de 1931 à ~1934).

Comment: D'ailleurs _lambda_ ne figure pas dans [_L'Argot de l'X_ de 1894](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k205446n), donc si le terme vient bien de l'X, son apparition se situe a priori entre 1894 et 1936.

Answer (score 7):

Il y a bien [une explication probable ici](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/un-quelque-chose-lambda.php):

*[...] par sa position dans le même alphabet, lambda est la lettre dont le nom n'est pas monosyllabique qui est placée la plus proche du milieu, donc à une position très moyenne, très quelconque, où elle ne peut pas briller, où elle est un peu noyée dans la masse, contrairement à l'alpha et à l'oméga, les première et dernière lettres.
Ce serait là l'explication de l'utilisation de cette lettre.*

Comment: Promis, je n'ai pas regardé ce qu'a posté @Joubarc, à qui je mets +1, du coup :)

Comment: Si c'est une consolation, tu m'as pris de vitesse sur l'edit du titre :-)

Answer (score 3):

Il y a [un épisode de *Merci Professeur !* consacré à la question](http://www.tv5monde.com/cms/chaine-francophone/lf/Merci-Professeur/p-17081-Lambda.htm?episode=742) (courte émission TV sur la langue française), où le linguiste [Bernard Cerquiglini](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Cerquiglini) propose cette explication :

> C'est seulement dans les années 1930 que le mot apparaît dans l'argot des grandes écoles. Il est synonyme de *banal*, *quelconque*. On traite en effet de *lambda* la queue des promotions de l'École polytechnique ; une ultime influence, sans doute, de la forme de la lettre grecque.

En somme, c'est le rapprochement entre la graphie de λ, et la **queue** d'une promotion (composée d'individus quelconques, probablement au sens de *de peu d'intérêt*), qui est proposé.

J'ai du mal à m'en convaincre, mais enfin c'est une explication de plus, et Bernard Cerquiglini semble assez versé dans ce genre de question. En tout cas sur la date c'est cohérent avec le fait que *lambda* [figure dans l'argot de l'X de 1936](http://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=nuoeAQAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=lambda) et pas dans [celui de 1894](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k205446n).

Answer (score 2):

Le Littré donne une étymologie très originale de lambda dans le sens de ordinaire :

Prononciation : lan-bda
Etymologie : Mot corrompu probablement de manate ou manatin, qui est conservé dans l'espagnol et qui est un mot galibi.

Le mot "galibi", signifiant "caillou" en gaélique, donc : ordinaire.

Le mot "manate" étant lui-même une dérive de "lamentin", célèbre espèce de cétacé herbivore (manate américain), ce qui boucle la boucle du "M" devenu "L".

Comment: Quelle édition ?  La [version en ligne que je connais](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/lambda/) n'indique rien de semblable.

Answer (score 0):

En lançant quelques recherche sur ngram, j'ai commencé à étayer une théorie qui voudrait que l'utilisation de plus en plus fréquente de l'expression "individu lambda" serait liée au [lambda-calcul](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-calcul).

En effet, l'utilisation de "individu lambda" ne fait son apparition que vers 1990 :

[image]

Sachant que lambda est utilisé en lambda-calcul pour désigner des fonctions anonymes, on notera la corrélation entre l'utilisation des deux expressions :

[image]
[image]

On pourra trouver une explication similaire sur [yahoo answer](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091205015837AAcIWCM), certes peu plébiscité.

Certes la théorie de la lettre médiane dans l'alphabet grec est plausible, mais pourquoi une utilisation si tardive alors?

Comment: Le sens de *lambda* est [attesté en 1938](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/pourquoi-lambda/1171#1171) et n'était probablement pas nouveau de cette année. Certes, le lambda-calcul existait, mais il était complètement confidentiel, surtout en France, avant les années 1960.

Answer (score 0):

En fait, c'est juste une expression utilisée dans la presse littéraire "lecteur lambda" (parce que lecteur commence par L) qui s'est étendue à "personne lambda" ou "individu lambda".

[Voici l'évolution des deux termes d'après GoogleBook.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=individu+lambda%2Clecteur+lambda&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindividu%20lambda%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clecteur%20lambda%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

Pour conforter l'idée de l'argot des grandes écoles, en math, les inconnues sont généralement représentés par les lettres x, y, z, et les paramètres *externes* par les lettres grecques lambda, mu. Typiquement pour une application linéaire on écrit:

> pour tous vecteurs X et Y, et pour tous réels lambda mu, ...

donc dans ces expressions mathématiques, lambda représente une valeur quelconque, qui plus est non pas dans l'espace lui-même mais dans l'ensemble des scalaires.

Par extension, lambda est devenu l'attribut de quelque chose de générique et de peu d'intérêt.

Answer (score 0):

Coucou c'est moi !

Bon, j'arrive avec un grand sac rempli de toutes les réponses à votre question, j'espère que ca vous fera plaisir, et ne vous inquietez pas, il y des pierres aussi dans les cadeaux pour ceux qui n'auront pas compris et qui voudront ; j'ai pensé a tout, et c'est mon génie, l'inconnu qui sortait de nul part et qui savait tout ce qui suffisait pour répondre au sujet du mot définissant le plus parfaitement le rien de spécial : Je suis l'homme qui tombe à pic.

Alors donc vous vous demandiez – qu'on y revienne un peu quand meme – :

> Pourquoi « lambda » ?

*(Pour les impatients j'ai mis un TLDR à la fin, pour les aventureux vous comprendrez que le TLDR était nécessaire parce que si j'avais eu par exemple le double de temps j'aurai produis sans aucune vergogne deux fois plus de paragraphe tout aussi sympathique que cette page).*

De la lecture de tous ces avis, ces connaissances, ces "bonnes raison";
On ne peut qu'être à chaque commentaire *plus conforté* dans l'idée que *lambda* est l'exact bon mot pour désigner ce que l'on le prétend désigner.

> Il semble en effet que n'importe quel autre aurait pu convenir, et pourtant c'est bien celui-ci que l'on à choisi.

Il apparait plutôt clair qu'au dela de toute explication qui se voudrait satisfaire définitivement comme méthode pour choisir avec exactitude **"Le bon mot pour ce qui est d'un commun absolu"** , on fait face ici à celui-ci sans explication.

**Lambda** aurait donc *"de fait"* – par constat, et simplement par celui-ci – cette particularité par rapport aux autre candidats d'être ***Tellement Commun qu'il en est d'une totale singularité***

Et c'est en cela qu'il rempli donc parfaitement son rôle, de par son double sens. Y chercher une *explication* est de fait une erreur et une errance garantie *(sauf si untel décide de se satisfaire d'une explication X ou Y à un instant T quelquonque, auquel cas voila l'explication satisfaite pour cette personne au titre... que celà lui suffit comme telle (pour être satisfaite)*.

Trève de troll, je me permet de mal citer un confrère de M.Etienne KLEIN sur le sujet du hasard pour vous amener à la raison toute simple qui fait de lambda le bon mot pour sa définition :

> Nous somme la somme d'improbabilités cumulées à des degrés tels qu'elles en sont négligeables, et pourtant c'est cet exact déroulé qui fait également que nous étions , *rétrospectivement* inéluctable

Voila un hasard bienheureux, évident et inexplicable, si ce n'est à l'hypthèse d'une nature strictement similaire et unique au libre arbitre et au destin mais qui en permettrait tout de même la distinction réelle et valide en deux aspect...

Lambda est le mot choisi comme tel pour représenter son propre double sens. N'importe quel mot creux, "valise" au possible aurait convenu. Il suffit ensuite par simple constat, "hasard" restrospectivement inéluctable, que celui-ci ai "mieux marché" qu'un autre ou recu "plus de célébrité" au fil du temps et malgré la différences des cultures.

Ainsi, il est aussi vain de se débattre de sur les explications qui poussent au choix du mot lambda que dans l'ensemble sur les "raison" qui poussent au choix de quelque mot que ce soit "en tant que mot". Un mot n'a aucune raison, ni aucune explication, c'est un contenant. C'est l'histoire qui en fait le contenu. Lambda n'avait pas ce sens, peut le perdre, mais le débat ici montre bien, au vu de l'armada d'outil statistiques, de théorie, de connaissance déballées, que le mot "lambda" est aujourd'hui très probablement au *top de sa carrière*, puisque jamais autant de spécificité, d'esprit pointus n'auront autaut fait de vent autour d'un mot désignant le pur commun comme inutile.
C'est avec tristesse que je me permet de vous prédire la perte "sèche" de vitesse de popularité de ce mot en tant que ce qu'il entend définir, et apelle malgrès tout d'or et déja ses successeurs présumé à se manifester et à commencer à démontrer en quoi ils sont les meilleurs, les plus spéciaux, les plus parfaits, pour définir ce qui n'est sans aucune commune mesure aussi banal qu'eux même.

Enfin je me permet de lancer en l'air au cas où ça puisse prendre un peu feu un truc du genre : "Mais finalement, Dieu ne serait-il pas parfaitement défini dans cette exception élémentaire ? Dieu ne serait-il finalement pas un individu lambda ? Un individu lambda dieu ?" 
(Je sens la preuve ontologique de godel qui me chatouille le cerveau là pour commencer à débattre, pas vous ?)

Et bien sur une dernière pour la route qui concerne absolument chacun d'entre (n|v)ous :

> Vous êtes chacun d'entre vous absolument et indiscutablement uniques. Et c'est le cas de tout le monde.

C'est cadeau.

J'espere que y'aura aussi un hippie pour venir nous démontrer que *ca veut bien dire alors que même si on est tous unique, on est tous ensemble un seul monsieur tout le monde, genre qui s'apellerai lambda, et qu'on est donc tous des frêre et soeurs, man*
Si celui-ci arrive c'est promis : je vous reviens dans un nouveau Topic pour qu'on débatte de pourquoi ce qu'il aura dit non seulement justifie l'inceste, mais en sus le rend inéluctable et omniprésent.

*TLDR :*

> Si d'aventure vous cherchiez quelle serait la question la plus parfaitement con à vous poser possible (C'est aussi ca la recherche), demandez vous simplement et exactement ceci : Pourquoi un mot X est utilisé pour définir une chose Y". Satisfait ou remboursé. Résultats garrantis.

PS : Je suis *hyper content* d'être tombé sur ce post, le genre de post qu'on ne rencontre qu'une fois dans sa vie.

Bon ok j'arrête.

Answer (score -1):

Cette expression me rappelle, pour ma part, *Le meilleur des mondes* d'Huxley, ainsi qu'à la lettre apposée aux boucliers des citoyens spartiates, les « égaux ».